# [No debug Flash player connection request]

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, away3d

I have a Problem with away 3d.I wanted to create an application and it was working fine till I had embedded 5 images in my program but as soon as I embed more than 5 images the flash develop stops responding [No debug Flash player connection request] showing me this message.Is it the problem with the number of images or should I do something else to include these images.

```
        [Embed(source="assets1/b1 copy.png")]
        private  var EarthImage:Class;
        private  var earth:Bitmap = new EarthImage();
        [Embed(source="assets1/balls.jpg")]
        private  var bac:Class;
        private  var bm:Bitmap = new bac();
        [Embed(source="assets1/1.png")]
        private  var bac1:Class;
        private var bm1:Bitmap = new bac1();
        [Embed(source="assets1/2.png")]
        private var bac2:Class;
        private  var bm2:Bitmap = new bac2();
        [Embed(source="assets1/3.png")]
        public var bac3:Class;
        public var bm3:Bitmap = new bac3();
        [Embed(source="assets1/4.png")]
        public var bac4:Class;
        public var bm4:Bitmap = new bac4();
        [Embed(source="assets1/5.png")]
        public var bac5:Class;
        public var bm5:Bitmap = new bac5();
        [Embed(source="assets1/6.png")]
        public var bac6:Class;
        public var bm6:Bitmap = new bac6();
        [Embed(source="assets1/7.png")]
        public var bac7:Class;
        public var bm7:Bitmap = new bac7();
        [Embed(source="assets1/8.png")]
        public var bac8:Class;
        public var bm8:Bitmap = new bac8();
        [Embed(source="assets1/9.png")]
        public var bac9:Class;
        public var bm9:Bitmap = new bac9();
        [Embed(source="assets1/10.png")]
        public var bac10:Class;
        public var bm10:Bitmap = new bac10();
        [Embed(source="assets1/11.png")]
        public var bac11:Class;
        public var bm11:Bitmap = new bac11();
        [Embed(source="assets1/12.png")]
        public var bac12:Class;
        public var bm12:Bitmap = new bac12();
        [Embed(source="assets1/13.png")]
        public var bac13:Class;
        public var bm13:Bitmap = new bac13();
        [Embed(source="assets1/14.png")]
        public var bac14:Class;
        public var bm14:Bitmap = new bac14();
        [Embed(source="assets1/15.png")]
        public var bac15:Class;
        public var bm15:Bitmap = new bac15();
        [Embed(source="assets1/16.png")]
        public  var bac16:Class;
        public  var bm16:Bitmap = new bac16();
        [Embed(source="assets1/17.png")]
        public var bac17:Class;
        public  var bm17:Bitmap = new bac17();
        [Embed(source="assets1/18.png")]
        public  var bac18:Class;
        public  var bm18:Bitmap = new bac18();
        [Embed(source="assets1/19.png")]
        public var bac19:Class;
        public  var bm19:Bitmap = new bac19();
        [Embed(source="assets1/20.png")]
        public  var bac20:Class;
        public  var bm20:Bitmap = new bac20()
```

This is the code I am using to embed the images into the application.

Comment: does this apply *whichever* 5 images you include?

Comment: Don't create those bitmapData there that's an overhead for the runtime since it needs to create all those objects before creating an instance of the class. Think about saving some CPU usage for the app and instead create your bitmapdatas in constructor or better yet on per need basis.

Comment: I've never seen the number of embedded files cause a problem. While the comment above is true, I don't think it's the cause of your problem. Have you confirmed that you're actually running a debug version of the Flash player? For example, an update to Chrome may have blown away the debug Flash player...

Comment: What size are those bitmaps? Probably you're runnin out of memory if you instantiate more than 5 big bitmaps. Also review the thresholds on the bitmapdata size for your Flash player version.